# Jenkinsfile error when using $() with sh or /bin/bash

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a step in my Jenkinsfile, that look like this:

```
steps {
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
              docker kill $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=nginx-example )'''
        sh '''docker build -t nginx-example .
              docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx-example'''
      }
```

And it errors like this

```
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]




Kill one or more running containers
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I run docker kill with $()? It only does not work in Jenkinsfile, while in Jenkins Pipeline it was working totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a docker running with the name `nginx-example`? If the docker is not running, then I'm getting the same error in bash as well:

```
# docker kill $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=nginx-example )
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
```

If it's in stopped state, I would suggest you to use `docker ps -a`